# Flash AS3 #2025 error occured, pass movieclip to the stage from the loader

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loader, movieclip

I'm just going to move the movieclip to the stage from the loader.

However I met an error "#2025" when I try to move or rotate the movieclip.

Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller

What's wrong in my code?

[Main Parent MC]

```
function loaderShow(url:String):void{
    var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loader_complete);
    loader.load(urlRequest);
    addChild(loader);
}

function loaderClose():void{
    loader.unload();
    removeChild(loader);
}

function loader_complete(evt:Event):void {
    var target_mc:Loader = evt.currentTarget.loader as Loader;
    target_mc.x = (stage.stageWidth - target_mc.width) / 2;
    target_mc.y = (stage.stageHeight - target_mc.height) / 2;
}

function addTextEmoticon(ty:int, target:DisplayObject):void{
    var mc:MovieClip = target as MovieClip;
    addChild(mc);
    mc.x = 10; // error occured #2025
    mc.y =20;  // error occured #2025
}
```

[Child MC - Loader]

```
function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var mc:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;
    root_movie.addTextEmoticon(1, mc);
    root_movie.loaderClose();
}
```

Comment: This error doesnt relate to x or y or rotation but with removeChild method.

Comment: Assuming this is all the relevant code - your click handler must be called more than once (or before your loadShow method runs) as it's either trying remove child on `loader` more than once, or before `loader` has been added.   Check if loader exists and is on the stage prior to attempting to remove it.   `if(loader && loader.parent) removeChild(loader);`

Comment: As pointed out by @SameerJain - doing `mc.x = 10` will not throw that kind of error so the line numbering must be off somehow for you.

Comment: Thank you @SameerJain. You're right. It's not related to position of movieclip.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis Thank you :) As you mentioned, I just add method for checking if loader was existed, then the problem has gone. Thank you very much :)